# unexpected unindent error when sending mail from .txt document

Tags: python, recursion, smtp

I am writing a program to send an email (from message.txt) to email addresses which are stored in email.txt. Sending an empty email works flawlessly, but if I use the txt or the message it throws the syntax error "unexpected unindent" on the very last line of code. Why is that and what can I do to solve it?

EDIT: I have read through other people's problems getting the same error, but their error's origin is very different to mine, hence I cannot conclude anything from their solutions...

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_email(user, pwd, recipients, subject):
    try:        
        with open('message.txt') as fp:
            # Create a text/plain message
            msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
        recipients = []
        with open('emails.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                    recipients.append(line.strip())
        #container
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')        
        msg['Subject'] = 'Your reminder'
        msg['From'] = 'example@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = ','.join(recipients)
        msg.attach(msg)
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(user, recipients, msg.as_string())
        server.close()
        print("Sent the email!")
send_email("example@gmail.com", "password", "Subject",     "A reminder")
```

Comment: Do _NOT_ use `except Exception` because it hides the actual problem from you. Remove that part, run the program again, and find out which line causes the infinite recursion.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you! I found that to be rather useless as well, I took that over from a different code I saw online. Without this statement it tells me that at the very last line there is an unexpected indent. But there is no unindent?

Comment: Please rewrite your question: add the complete error message and the exact code (but please do NOT insert so many blank lines between your statements; it is bad style, and it makes your code hard to read).

Comment: You entirely removed your `except` code but left your `try` statement. That's the reason for your indent error. Remove the try statement too and unindent the code or add a proper exception as suggestion by @DYZ

Comment: @DYZ thanks for your feedback. I edited the code to leave out the blank lines and made it more compact.

Comment: Your code has `try` but no `except`, as pointed out by @VineethSai. It is grammatically invalid. Please fix it before going any further.

Comment: @VineethSai I just removed the try statement and and unindented everything affected. I now got a load of errors resulting in another maximum recursion depth error...

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I have now fixed the issue: It was the MIMEmultipart module which was unneeded and caused problems. Thank you again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You've used the variable name msg as both the MIMEText message attachment and the MIMEMultipart message container. In the code below, I've changed the name for the MIMEText variable to be strMessage.

The unexpected unindent occurs because the try block isn't complete. Either add *something* to the try block to complete the compound statement:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_email(user, pwd, recipients, subject):
    try:        
        with open('message.txt') as fp:
            # Create a text/plain message
            strMessage = MIMEText(fp.read())
        recipients = []
        with open('emails.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                    recipients.append(line.strip())
        #container
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')        
        msg['Subject'] = 'Your reminder'
        msg['From'] = 'example@gmail.com'
        msg['To'] = ','.join(recipients)
        msg.attach(strMessage)
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(user, recipients, strMessage.as_string())
        server.close()
        print("Sent the email!")
    finally:
        pass
send_email("example@gmail.com", "password", "Subject",     "A reminder")
```

Or omit the try entirely:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_email(user, pwd, recipients, subject):
            with open('message.txt') as fp:
                # Create a text/plain message
                strMessage = MIMEText(fp.read())
            recipients = []
            with open('emails.txt') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                        recipients.append(line.strip())
            #container
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['Subject'] = 'Your reminder'
            msg['From'] = 'example@gmail.com'
            msg['To'] = ','.join(recipients)
            msg.attach(strMessage)
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(user, pwd)
            server.sendmail(user, recipients, strMessage.as_string())
            server.close()
            print("Sent the email!")
send_email("example@gmail.com", "password", "Subject",     "A reminder")
```